# Modeling a spring mass damper with variable damping

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, control-theory

I am trying to figure out how to come up with a transfer function for a spring mass damper with variable damping. The problem is when I try to come up with a transfer function for my equation I get a convolution but not sure how to handle this with a variable input. Is there any way for me to linearize the system so that I can get a transfer function for it?

$$
m\ddot{x}=k(w-x)+u(\dot{w}-\dot{x})
$$

Where w is the displacement of the road surface and u is the variable damping rate. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Dou you have two inputs w and u, or is this w just initial rest position of the mass? If w is initial rest position (i.e. constant), then you can take it as zero and simplify. However, the system is still non-linear system and you can linearize it around some operating point (given certain value for states and inputs(s)). To sum up, you can linearize system to get a transfer function, but transfer function is from single input to single output. If you have two inputs, after linearization you are going to get two transfer functions: from u to x, and from w to x (if w is also input).

Comment: Also, linearization is done at some operating point and may not be a good approximation for all variations in states and inputs.